# rpcbind authorization problems

Tags: python, linux, sockets, authorization, sunrpc

I am using `rpcbind` (SunRPC) on Arch linux and the Python `rpc.py` (which use standard python socket module) interface for comunication with it. Every time I try to send a request for registration or unregistration to `rpcbind`, I get message that I am rejected for security reasons. The only situation where everything works is when I call `rpcbind` in insecure mode (`rpcbind -i`), but I really want to make everything works in secure mode. I found information from the rpcbind datasheet that I can make a request in secure mode only from the loopback address, but I have tried every approach I had knew to make such a socket and everything fell down. How do I connect to `rpcbind` in secure mode?